# How to make nestjs watch for specific node module?

Tags: webpack, nestjs

In my application, I'd like to make NestJS reload dev mode once a specific node modules changes.

I run this script: `nest build --watch`

my `nest-cli.json` file is:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
    "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "webpack": true,
        "webpackConfigPath": "./webpack.config.js",
        "deleteOutDir": true
    }
}
```

And my webpack file is:

```js
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const { RunScriptWebpackPlugin } = require('run-script-webpack-plugin');

const { version } = require('../../package.json');

const configuration = (options, webpack) => ({
    ...options,
    entry: ['webpack/hot/poll?100', options.entry],
    externals: [
        nodeExternals({
            allowlist: ['webpack/hot/poll?100'],
        }),
    ],
    plugins: [
        ...options.plugins,
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin({
            paths: [/\.d\.ts$/],
        }),
        new RunScriptWebpackPlugin({ name: options.output.filename, autoRestart: false }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __PACKAGE_VERSION__: JSON.stringify(version),
        }),
    ],
});

module.exports = configuration;
```

I want to make NestJS recompile in the dev mode once this package changes: `node_modules/@blabla/common`
Because this package is private one linked to my project.